# Open application only with NFC tag

Tags: android, security, nfc, android-launcher

Is it possible to write an android application such that it is *only* able to open by scanning the device with an NFC tag?

A similar question was asked here but a clear answer was not given. 
[I want an android app to open using nfc tag only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257314/i-want-an-android-app-to-open-using-nfc-tag-only)

Is it as simple as deleting:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

from the AndroidManifest.xml file and then adding an NDEF_DISCOVERED intent to start the app?

*EDIT*
The goal is to have a secure application that will *only* work for a user with a specific NFC tag (ie not someone who has found/stolen the phone). So the application is to do with moving money around and I want to use NFC to determine the identity of the user. I could use a remote database with encrypted passwords but people don't want to

a) type in a complicated password everytime they open an app and
b) may not trust a third party if money is involved.

So I'm looking for some sort of security system using NFC that verifies a users identity. How secure is face recognition with Android? If I stored the face recognition data of a verirified user on an NFC tag who then checked it versus a scan of the users face onStart() how secure is that?

One more thing. If I'm trying to secure the app itself should I exit the app onPause() so that if the app was previously being used by the true owner of the account but didn't exit the app then a different person could not resume the app?

Comment: That will remove the launcher icon, so it is a simple way. It won't provide you with any real security though. There are other ways to make your app launch.

Comment: To achieve a level of security could I immediately check the content of the tag and exit if the content is not as expected?

Comment: Look that: [Start an Android app/intent from an NFC tag?][1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615240/start-an-android-app-intent-from-an-nfc-tag

Comment: Please clarify your question: 1) Do you want to stop users from opening the app thru normal means e.g. press on app icon in app drawer? 2) NDEF is the only type of tag you are looking at?

Comment: Also, which exact type of card are you using e.g. Mifare Java card?

Comment: @fuzzybee 1)yes 2)It doesn't have to be NDEF that's just what I'm used to 3) Mifare Java card? I don't know what that is!